# Prevent screen from moving when clicking on <a href=></a>

Tags: html, css

I'm using `<a href>` element along with `:target` css selector to show a `<div>` which by default is set to `display:none`. Problem is, that when I click on the link to show that `<div>`, it is automatically scrolling down my site towards that `<div>`.

Is there a way to stop the screen movement?

Unfortunately I am not yet proficient in anything besides CSS and HTML.

Comment: I think you will need JS for that as you have 2 possibilities: 1. Avoid the scroll by JS 2. use a different element than an anchor, but then you will have no :target functionality and will have to show your target element by js

Comment: As iv said, i doesnt know js yet (i barely started learning it a week agoo). I suspect that there is fairly easy way to do what im stugglind to do here with bare CSS and HTML, so while im grateful for all JS ideas (ill save them for later), the best solution would be such which is limited css and html (if even theres any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but you could use a basic css work around:

**[CSS only Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7sYzU/1/)**

```
#div1 {
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#div1:target {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -110px;
    padding-top: 110px;
}
#div2 {
    background:red;
}

<a href="#div1">Click to show</a>

<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">Content</div>
</div>
```

If you need it to be a little more flexible you can add some js...

**[More Flexible Example with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/RQK7Q/3/)**

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('#div1').css({
        'margin-top': 0 - $('#div1').position().top + $(window).scrollTop(),
            'padding-top': $('#div1').position().top - $(window).scrollTop()
    });
});
```

Basically you're pulling the top of div1 up with the negative margin and then pushing div2 back down with the padding, so that the top of div1 rests at the top of the window... Like I said its a hack but it does the trick.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)** to avoid this. Something like this:

```
$('a.yourclass').click(function(e)
{
    //your code
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

OR:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">link</a>
```

Comment: That would stop the link from being followed. If the link isn't followed, then the fragment ID in the URL won't change which would defeat the object.

Comment: @Quentin:- And how about this one: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="somefunction(); return false;">anchor</a>

Comment: And what would `somefunction()` do? Set `location.hash`? That takes us right back to where we started, but with much uglier code and a dependancy on JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

in the link enter:

```
<a href="javascript:void();">Link here</a>
```

Comment: The question states that the point is to trigger a change of `:target`. You can't change where the `href` points without breaking that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need JS anyway:

```
// (in jQuery)
$el.on('click', function(e) {
  // find current scroll position
  var pos = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  // let normal action propagate etc

  // in the next available frame (async, hence setTimeout), reset scroll posiion
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, pos);
  }, 1);
})
```

I don't know if this will flicker the screen. It might. It's a horrible hack either way.

In my Chrome, there's no flicker: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/LEwNd/1/show/

Comment: If you make such a solution, I would save the x-position too. Just in case it was there :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to tell the browser we don't want it to act:

1. The main way is to use the event object. There's a method
   event.preventDefault().
2. If the handler is assigned using on (not by
       addEventListener), then we can just return false from it.

Example:
`<a href="/" onclick="return false">Click here</a>` 
or
 `<a href="/" onclick="event.preventDefault()">here</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Those links are anchor-links and by default made for those jumps :) You could use JS to prevent the default behaviour in some way. For example using jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

or by default add `return false;` to the links

Comment: That would stop the link from being followed. If the link isn't followed, then the fragment ID in the URL won't change which would defeat the object.

Comment: you could still do that by js if you need it. But if he doesn't want the jump I would usually not even use links at all  :)

Comment: @Quentin: do you have an own solution if you don't like the ones provided?

Comment: Do what by JS? Follow the link? Adding JavaScript that does precisely those two things (1. Stop the link from being followed and 2. Follow the link) seems excessively pointless!

Comment: Don't confuse "not liking" with "explaining that they are *not* solutions".

Comment: Well I haven't seen your solution yet without using JS... So where is it? And yes, you can add the Hash-Tag to the url by JS

Comment: I haven't got a solution. I don't think there is a solution. If you add a fragment id (which is not a hashtag, that's a thing you use to mark search terms on social media) then you scroll the page to the element with that id. So if you add it with JS then it recreates the problem that using JS to prevent the link from being followed solved!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using :target all together and just use onclick event.

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}

<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"></a>
```